# Why do 2 delegate instances return the same hashcode?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, hashcode

Take the following:

```
  var x =  new Action(() => { Console.Write("") ; });
  var y = new Action(() => { });
  var a = x.GetHashCode();
  var b = y.GetHashCode();
  Console.WriteLine(a == b);
  Console.WriteLine(x == y);
```

This will print:

```
True
False
```

Why is the hashcode the same?

It is kinda surprising, and will make using delegates in a `Dictionary` as slow as a `List` (aka `O(n)` for lookups).

**Update:**

The question is why. IOW who made such a (silly) decision?

A better hashcode implementation would have been:

```
return Method ^ Target == null ? 0 : Target.GetHashcode();
// where Method is IntPtr
```

Comment: Did you try to put a some code into second delegate too , and only after check Hash code ?

Comment: Don't know exactly WHY it happens, but just as an idea, you may implement your own Hash mechanism, or wrap those actions in a class and override its GetHashCode to fit your needs.

Comment: Just for reference the contract for `Delegate.Equals` is: "Determines whether the specified object and the current delegate are of the same type and share the same targets, methods, and invocation list."

Comment: @leppie although I must confess that I have never had a scenario where I wanted to use a delegate as a *key* in a dictionary. As the value, *for sure* - just not the key.

Comment: Your "better implementation" has the same mistake as the one I originally made: You're calling the overriden `Target.GetHashCode` instead of using referential equality.

Comment: @EricLippert: Some comment? Sorry for spam :)

Comment: I'm currently building a simple task scheduler, that takes `Action` as input. Trying to figure out a way to UNIQUELY identify actions. Haven't found one yet :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easy! Since here is the implementation of the `GetHashCode` <s>(sitting on the base class `Delegate`):</s>

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return base.GetType().GetHashCode();
}
```

(sitting on the base class `MulticastDelegate` which **will call above**):

```
public sealed override int GetHashCode()
{
    if (this.IsUnmanagedFunctionPtr())
    {
        return ValueType.GetHashCodeOfPtr(base._methodPtr);
    }
    object[] objArray = this._invocationList as object[];
    if (objArray == null)
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
    int num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ((int) this._invocationCount); i++)
    {
        num = (num * 0x21) + objArray[i].GetHashCode();
    }
    return num;
}
```

Using tools such as Reflector, we can see the code and it seems like the default implementation is as *strange* as we see above.

The type value here will be `Action`. Hence the result above is **correct**.

## UPDATE

Comment: To be honest `return 42;` would be *about* as useful as the `Delegate` implementation (although `MulticastDelegate` looks better)

Comment: However, `GetHashCode` is overridden in turn on `MulticastDelegate`, which adds up the hash codes of all the subscribed delegates (if it's actually a multicast delegate). The plot thickens...

Comment: @Marc: `Object.GetType()` does a dynamic lookup of the actual object type at runtime, so it isn't the same as `typeof(object).GetHashCode()`. It actually returns different values for each delegate type (but the same value for all instances of that type)

Comment: @Marc: I just scrubbed my comment; The `MulticastDelegate` implementation is just as broken because the combined hashcode will be generated by calling up to the dodgy base implementation for each target. You'll get different hashcodes if you have different *numbers* of targets, but if you have the same number of targets then you're going to get the same hashcode!

Comment: @thecoop: And how often to you subscribe multiple methods to a delegate in a non-event situation? I can probably count the number of times on half a hand :)

Comment: @thecoop - yeah, scrubbed that

Answer (score 4):

My first attempt of a better implementation:

```
public class DelegateEqualityComparer:IEqualityComparer<Delegate>
{
    public bool Equals(Delegate del1,Delegate del2)
    {
        return (del1 != null) && del1.Equals(del2);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Delegate obj)
    {
            if(obj==null)
                return 0;
            int result = obj.Method.GetHashCode() ^ obj.GetType().GetHashCode();
            if(obj.Target != null)
                result ^= RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(obj);
            return result;
    }
}
```

The quality of this should be good for single cast delegates, but not so much for multicast delegates (If I recall correctly Target/Method return the values of the last element delegate).

But I'm not really sure if it fulfills the contract in all corner cases.

Hmm it looks like quality requires referential equality of the targets.

Comment: @adrianm: Your comment does not make sense.

Comment: Hmm interesting thought @adrianm. I think the specification of equals might mean referential equality instead of `.Equals()`

Comment: Modified it to use referential equality of targets.

Comment: @leppie: If something within the target changes, the delegate's hashcode will also change, i.e. you break the contract of dictionary keys. I can't pinpoint exactly why but I think the strange hashcode implementation has something to do with the equals definition and immutable invocation lists.

Comment: @adrianm: I understand what you mean, but one should never use keys like that!

Comment: @CodesInChaos Could you do this ->

public int GetHashCode(Delegate? obj)
            {
                if (obj == null)
                    return 0;
                else
                {
                    long asdf = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(obj).ToInt64();
                    return (int)(asdf % 920574309);
                } 
            }

Answer (score 1):

This smells like some of the cases mentioned in this thread, maybe it will give you some pointers on this behaviour. else, you could log it there :-)

[What's the strangest corner case you've seen in C# or .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/194484/65747)

Rgds GJ

Comment: which post, specifically? it isn't related to the one in the question, if that is what you mean

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN :

> The default implementation of
>   GetHashCode does not guarantee
>   uniqueness or consistency; therefore,
>   it must not be used as a unique object
>   identifier for hashing purposes.
>   Derived classes must override
>   GetHashCode with an implementation
>   that returns a unique hash code. For
>   best results, the hash code must be
>   based on the value of an instance
>   field or property, instead of a static
>   field or property.

So if you have not overwritten the GetHashCode method, it may return the same. I suspect this is because it generates it from the definition, not the instance.

Comment: That the contract allows this is obvious. The question is why the implementation is this bad.

Comment: My point was that MS evade this by saying you need to override the default implementation to get unique values. It means that the default implementation is useless. As Aliostad points out above, and I tried to say, the default is based on the type, not the instance. It is probably because MS hates us.

Comment: Now if only we could override the hashcode in C#. I know it is possible in the CLR (via IL) to construct custom (and very slow) delegates.

Comment: @leppie: If you're concerned about performance in hashtables etc then you could just pass an `IEqualityComparer<T>` that "does the right thing" into your `Dictionary<K,V>`/`HashSet<T>` etc constructors, or knock-up custom `DelegateDictionary<K,V>`/`DelegateHashSet<T>` that do it automatically.

Comment: @leppie: Admittedly it's not ideal, and something you really shouldn't need to do in the first place, but it's probably an adequate workaround.

Comment: @LukeH: I agree, and will do that if ever needed :)

Comment: @LukeH to do that we first need to figure out what the right thing is. And that's not that easy. So it'd be really nice if MS supplied a good default implementation.